# Cant connect wirelessly Windows 7 toshiba laptop

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop, intel-centrino

so I have a toshiba laptop, and the wireless network card inside is an Intel Centrino N-2200.My laptop never had connectivity problem until today, I turned off the wifi access on the laptop(with the button on the keyboard) for maybe an hour, then I turned it back on, and all I get is this icon in the task bar:

[image: red error]

and the Centrino doesnt seem to get the IP?:

[image]

the black mark hide my IP adress.As you can see,theres nothing under "Centrino N-2200"

and its remains without getting an IP adress.Wired connection using cable work fine.I tried to:

```
-reboot laptop once
-reinitialise IP adress of the Centrino(without the Configfree utility)
-use windows connectivity problem solving
```

The problem still remains.Im able to wirelessly connect with other device without problems.Its not my router.I dont get it.I didnt drop my laptop.Nothing.Just a usual day(I take care of my laptop).All I did was turn off Wifi for an hour and thats it.

Thank you

Comment: There are a number of different ways Windows can shut WiFi. check the following: Airplane Mode (see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/what-is-airplane-mode), removing a specific WiFi connection, and shutting all WiFi. See http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/network-wifi/3279135/how-to-turn-wireless-connectivity-on-or-off-in-windows-7/  and http://www.math.uh.edu/~dave/help/win7wlan/index.html for more help.

Comment: Already tried that.Still doesnt work

Comment: Updated the card drivers? The "config-free" application is, to be brutally honest, completely useless as Windows has built-in wireless manager that is perfectly good enough.